# SMS Message with multiple recipients - Android message sending limit

Tags: android, sms, limit

When an SMS message is sent with multiple recipients, does Android count as one message or multiple messages?

In particular does it count as one message against the hourly message limit set by Android after which you get `Too many messages are being sent...` box?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple recipients count as multiple SMS messages and will add to your quota.
Basically you dispatch a message for each recipient, and [this](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8671824&postcount=40) discussion suggests that this limit seems to be imposed the [SMSDispatcher](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/telephony/+/454c5783e7695feec276325920550b2d4dcc3e16/src/java/com/android/internal/telephony/SMSDispatcher.java).